# Atom remote project folder with source control

Tags: git, ssh, atom-editor

I have set up a nuclide server on my aws instance and from Atom I can connect to a remote folder on the server. Atom automatically pushes all my local edits to the server. 
If you have a local project folder, Atom automatically highlights the uncommitted changes in the folder tree pane. 
My remote folder is under source control (Git) on the server, but I cannot see the uncommitted changes. 
How can one use the Atom source control feature with remote folders?

Comment: Is your remote folder itself under Git? Or does your remote Git repo to which you are pushing to as a hook which then checkout the remote folder you would be working in? (the point being, those folders themselves would not be managed by Git directly)

Comment: My remote folder itself is under git and is on AWS. My remote Git repo is on Bitucket but I use it only to push from AWS to bitbucket. Atom synchronizes with the AWS remote folder. So I want to use the git repo on AWS for the Atom tree viewer showing its uncommitted changes.

Comment: Remotes on bitbucket don't have uncommitted changes... as they don't have a worktree?

Comment: bitbucket is not the case, it's just another remote git repository. my remote (remote to atom) is on a server with local (local on the server) git

Comment: Were you able to find an answer?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I think it’s not possible